# Converse of Abel's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I know that a non conditional converse of Abel's theorem is not true, but is there a proof for the converse given certain conditions. So if $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ converges when $|x|<1$ and if $a_k\ge0\forall k$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-} f(x) = l \in\mathbb{R},$ prove that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k=l$.

Is there a proof out there for this? I find plenty of information about Abel's theorem, but nothing on this conditional converse.

Comment: It is indeed true. Here is a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4661522/930811

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've stated is the converse to Abel's theorem, which isn't true in general. That is, it's not the case that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \, a_k$ converges. A paper which gives conditions under which a converse does hold is "The converse to Abel's theorem on power series" by H. Delange in Annals of Math. 50 No.1 (1949)

Comment: Are you sure? I think with the added condition that an≥0, it would hold. Maybe there is a counter example

Comment: Can I find this paper anywhere?

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal The paper is available on JSTOR. If you register with them, you can read it online for free.

Comment: I just went through the paper, and there's no mention of the case $a_k\ge0\forall k$

Comment: Assuming you're talking about https://doi.org/10.2307/1969354

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal I'm not claiming that what the OP wrote is incorrect; I just suggested he look at the paper. If you think the statement is true, try and prove it.

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal It looks like this converse is true and not too difficult to prove.

Comment: I proved it: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4661522/930811